# Errors running Step function using Map state

Tags: aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to run crawlers in parallel using Map. I'm listing crawlers using tags. This the code I'm using. Please let me know what changes I need to make to my code given below in terms of passing variables at each stage of step function. I'm passing input as "tags": {"type": "parallel"}

```
    {
      "Comment": "A utility state machine to run all Glue Crawlers that match tags",
      "StartAt": "Get Glue Crawler List",
      "States": {
        "Get Glue Crawler List": {
          "Next": "Run Glue Crawlers",
          "OutputPath": "$.CrawlerNames",
          "Parameters": {
            "Tags.$": "$.tags"
          },
          "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:glue:listCrawlers",
          "Retry": [
            {
              "BackoffRate": 5,
              "ErrorEquals": [
                "States.ALL"
              ],
              "IntervalSeconds": 2,
              "MaxAttempts": 3
            }
          ],
          "Type": "Task"
        },
        "Run Glue Crawlers": {
          "End": true,
          "Iterator": {
            "StartAt": "StartCrawler",
            "States": {
              "GetCrawler": {
                "Next": "Is Running?",
                "Parameters": {
                  "Name.$": "$"
                },
                "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:glue:getCrawler",
                "ResultPath": "$.response.get_crawler",
                "Retry": [
                  {
                    "BackoffRate": 2,
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                      "States.ALL"
                    ],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 1,
                    "MaxAttempts": 8
                  }
                ],
                "Type": "Task"
              },
              "Is Running?": {
                "Choices": [
                  {
                    "Next": "Wait for Crawler To Complete",
                    "Or": [
                      {
                        "StringEquals": "RUNNING",
                        "Variable": "$.response.get_crawler.Crawler.State"
                      },
                      {
                        "StringEquals": "STOPPING",
                        "Variable": "$.response.get_crawler.Crawler.State"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "Default": "Prepare Output",
                "Type": "Choice"
              },
              "Prepare Output": {
                "End": true,
                "Parameters": {
                  "LastCrawl.$": "$.response.get_crawler.Crawler.LastCrawl",
                  "crawler_name.$": "$.crawler_name"
                },
                "Type": "Pass"
              },
              "StartCrawler": {
                "Catch": [
                  {
                    "Comment": "Crawler Already Running, just continue to monitor",
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                      "Glue.CrawlerRunningException"
                    ],
                    "Next": "GetCrawler",
                    "ResultPath": "$.response.start_crawler"
                  }
                ],
                "Next": "GetCrawler",
                "Parameters": {
                  "Name.$": "$"
                },
                "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:glue:startCrawler",
                "ResultPath": "$.start_crawler",
                "Retry": [
                  {
                    "BackoffRate": 1,
                    "Comment": "EntityNotFoundException - Fail immediately",
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                      "Glue.EntityNotFoundException"
                    ],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 1,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                  },
                  {
                    "BackoffRate": 1,
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                      "Glue.CrawlerRunningException"
                    ],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 1,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                  }
                ],
                "Type": "Task"
              },
              "Wait for Crawler To Complete": {
                "Next": "GetCrawler",
                "Seconds": 5,
                "Type": "Wait"
              }
            }
          },
          "ResultPath": null,
          "Type": "Map"
        }
      }
    }
```

Please assist in terms of input and output at various steps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't reviewed your code, but you can find working examples for this linked below, including a blog post that describes the details. One thing you will notice in the example linked here is modularization by using a separate workflow for running a crawler and invoking that by service integration in higher level workflows. This helps with reuse as well as making things a bit easier to view and understand.

Blog Post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/orchestrating-aws-glue-crawlers-using-aws-step-functions/

Sample Code: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-stepfunctions-examples/blob/main/sam/demo-manage-glue-crawlers-with-step-functions/template.yaml

Comment: Thanks Justin. I had seen this link. We wanted to have just 1 step function instead of a nested function, hence we tried to implement it as per the code above. We are getting issue in terms of passing the right parameters to next function/step of a state machine, hence asked on this forum hoping to get some inputs

Answer (score 0):

you need to switch your map to distributed and use state input to retrieve the list.

```
{
  "Comment": "A utility state machine to run all Glue Crawlers that match tags",
  "StartAt": "Get Glue Crawler List",
  "States": {
    "Get Glue Crawler List": {
      "Next": "Run Glue Crawlers",
      "OutputPath": "$.CrawlerNames",
      "Parameters": {
        "Tags.$": "$.tags"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:glue:listCrawlers",
      "Retry": [
        {
          "BackoffRate": 5,
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 3
        }
      ],
      "Type": "Task"
    },
    "Run Glue Crawlers": {
      "End": true,
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "StartCrawler",
        "States": {
          "GetCrawler": {
            "Next": "Is Running?",
            "Parameters": {
              "Name.$": "$"
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:glue:getCrawler",
            "ResultPath": "$.response.get_crawler",
            "Retry": [
              {
                "BackoffRate": 2,
                "ErrorEquals": [
                  "States.ALL"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 1,
                "MaxAttempts": 8
              }
            ],
            "Type": "Task"
          },
          "Is Running?": {
            "Choices": [
              {
                "Next": "Wait for Crawler To Complete",
                "Or": [
                  {
                    "StringEquals": "RUNNING",
                    "Variable": "$.response.get_crawler.Crawler.State"
                  },
                  {
                    "StringEquals": "STOPPING",
                    "Variable": "$.response.get_crawler.Crawler.State"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "Default": "Prepare Output",
            "Type": "Choice"
          },
          "Prepare Output": {
            "End": true,
            "Parameters": {
              "LastCrawl.$": "$.response.get_crawler.Crawler.LastCrawl",
              "crawler_name.$": "$.crawler_name"
            },
            "Type": "Pass"
          },
          "StartCrawler": {
            "Catch": [
              {
                "Comment": "Crawler Already Running, just continue to monitor",
                "ErrorEquals": [
                  "Glue.CrawlerRunningException"
                ],
                "Next": "GetCrawler",
                "ResultPath": "$.response.start_crawler"
              }
            ],
            "Next": "GetCrawler",
            "Parameters": {
              "Name.$": "$"
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:glue:startCrawler",
            "ResultPath": "$.start_crawler",
            "Retry": [
              {
                "BackoffRate": 1,
                "Comment": "EntityNotFoundException - Fail immediately",
                "ErrorEquals": [
                  "Glue.EntityNotFoundException"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 1,
                "MaxAttempts": 0
              },
              {
                "BackoffRate": 1,
                "ErrorEquals": [
                  "Glue.CrawlerRunningException"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 1,
                "MaxAttempts": 0
              }
            ],
            "Type": "Task"
          },
          "Wait for Crawler To Complete": {
            "Next": "GetCrawler",
            "Seconds": 5,
            "Type": "Wait"
          }
        },
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "DISTRIBUTED",
          "ExecutionType": "STANDARD"
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": null,
      "Type": "Map",
      "Label": "RunGlueCrawlers",
      "MaxConcurrency": 1000
    }
  }
}
```